# How to avoid padding so that extra bytes are not used by a structure

Tags: c++, c, gcc

One of my arrays takes 14 bytes but in a map file it shows as 16 bytes (i.e. next variable is allocated after 16 bytes of memory).
I want it not to use more than 14 bytes, i.e padding space should not come in map file.

What option do I have for same?

Can it be done using any compiler option?

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why do you think you want to do this? What precisely is in your array? Are you sure it doesn't *require* 4-byte alignment on your platform?

Comment: It seems you consider this an error, fluke, mistake, oversight or bug. However, there are several good reasons to store array elements this way. Can you provide your reasons why it should not?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at using `#pragma pack` around your structure. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html for some docs.

Try `#pragma pack(1)` just before then `#pragma pack()` just after the structure definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your platform may have the option 'packed' for sections. Sections having this are then aligned to byte